# Is there a possible solution to the error I'm getting on this java program?

Tags: java, class, formatting

I am trying to fix this code because it's not running due to a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`. It's confusing me because I've never encountered this error before.

The code has to solve expressions such as `3 + 4 * 5`, while following PEMDAS rules, such as multiplying comes before adding, etc. I would also prefer it to use keyboard input, which I tried to do myself which made matters worse, so I decided to just remove it.

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.Integer.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;
import java.lang.*;
class ExpressionSolver_Rumenov
{
    private ArrayList<String> list;
    private String expression;
    private String trimmedExp;
    private String evaluated;
    private int eval;

    public ExpressionSolver_Rumenov(String s)
    {
        list=new ArrayList<String>();
        expression=s;
        trimmedExp=s.trim();
        for (int x=0; x<trimmedExp.length(); x++)
        {
            list.add(""+trimmedExp.charAt(x));
        }
    }

    public void setExpression(String s)
    {
        expression=s;
        trimmedExp=s.trim();
        list.clear();
        for (int x=0; x<trimmedExp.length(); x++)
        {
            list.add(""+trimmedExp.charAt(x));
        }        
    }

    public void solveExpression()
    {
        eval=0;
        for (int x=0; x<list.size(); x++)
        {
            if (list.get(x).equals("*")||list.get(x).equals("/"))
            {
                if (list.get(x).equals("*"))
                {
                    list.set(x-1, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(list.get(x-1))*Integer.parseInt(list.get(x+1))));
                    list.remove(x+1);
                    list.remove(x);

                }

                else if(list.get(x).equals("/"))
                {
                    list.set(x-1, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(list.get(x-1))/Integer.parseInt(list.get(x+1))));
                    list.remove(x+1);
                    list.remove(x);

                }
            }

        }

        for (int x=0; x<list.size(); x++)
        {
            if (list.get(x).equals("-"))
            {
                list.set(x-1, String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(list.get(x-1))-Integer.parseInt(list.get(x+1))));
                list.remove(x);
                list.remove(x+1);
            }

            else if (list.get(x).equals("+"))
            {
                list.remove(x);
            }
        }
        for (int x=0; x<list.size(); x++)
        {
            if (list.get(x).equals(" "))
            {
                list.remove(x);
            }

            list.set(x, list.get(x).trim());
        }

        for (int x=0; x<list.size(); x++)
        {
            eval+=Integer.parseInt(list.get(x));            
        }

        evaluated=String.valueOf(eval);


    }

    public String toString( )
    {
        return evaluated;
    }
}

public class Lab04
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        ExpressionSolver_Rumenov test = new ExpressionSolver_Rumenov("3 + 5");
        test.solveExpression();
        out.println(test.toString());

        test.setExpression("3 * 5");
        test.solveExpression();
        out.println(test);

        test.setExpression("3 - 5");
        test.solveExpression();
        out.println(test);

        test.setExpression("3 / 5");
        test.solveExpression();
     out.println(test);

     test.setExpression("5 * 5 + 2 / 2 - 8 + 5 * 5 - 2");
        test.solveExpression();
        out.println(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your post and put the full exception stack trace to it

Comment: Please include the detailed error message you get including the stack trace.

Comment: did you ever print the content of your list to console to see what's actually in it?

Comment: Provide print outline for your inputs, I believe you have a mistake with brackets ()

Answer (score 0):

Acording to the JavaDocs from the Oracle, the NumberFormatException:

> Thrown to indicate that the application has attempted to convert a
>   string to one of the numeric types, but that the string does not have
>   the appropriate format.

Your problem is that you are trying to convert someting that is not a number into a number. The problem is probably from the parsing, like reading spaces and trying to convert them into numbers.

EDIT:
For the parsing I advise you to look at the "Shunting Yard" Algorithm in the Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to parse a `" "` character into an Integer at line `eval+=Integer.parseInt(list.get(x));`. This is happening because you are not properly removing the spaces from the list.

Here, you are running a loop on the  `x<list.size()` condition and when loop runs, you are also removing elements from it. You can not dynamically change the list size when you are comparing the loop termination with list.size(). This is not how you loop through the list.

```
        // not a correct way
        for (int x=0; x<list.size(); x++)
        {
            if (list.get(x).equals(" "))
            {
                list.remove(x);
            }

            list.set(x, list.get(x).trim());
        }
```

Instead, you should use list Iterator. Like this,

```
    // correct way
    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if(iter.next().equals(" "))
            iter.remove();
    }
```

You should update your code wherever you are iterating through list and removing the elements from it at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The bottom line is that you're trying to feed a non-Integer character to `Integer.parseInt()`. If you fix the expressions in your `Lab04` driver class, you'll see that everything works properly.

For example, instead of this:

```
ExpressionSolver_Rumenov test = new ExpressionSolver_Rumenov("3 + 5");
```

Try this, with the space characters removed:

```
ExpressionSolver_Rumenov test = new ExpressionSolver_Rumenov("3+5");
```

You probably want a more fault tolerant program, however, so you have some work to do, especially if you want users to be able to input their own data.

I think you might be misunderstanding what `String.trim()` does. The `trim()` method removes leading and trailing whitespace from a String, so if you have a tab character at the beginning of your String and a newline at the end, `trim()` will get rid of those.

What `trim()` will not do, however, is get rid of whitespace interspersed throughout a String. For that, you need to prune out the whitespace yourself, or just ignore whitespace characters.

To remove space characters from within the String, in your `setExpression` method, replace:

```
expression=s;
```

with

```
expression = s.replaceAll("\\s+","");
```

Of course, you can still just ignore whitespace. Instead of:

```
char c = trimmedExp.charAt(x);
list.add("" + c);
```

Try:

```
char c = trimmedExp.charAt(x);
if(c != " ")
{
    list.add("" + c);
}
```

Remember that you're comparing `Character` in this case, so `==` should be used, rather than `.equals()`.

Answer (score 0):

the scope of (.trim() ) is removing the spaces before and after the String expression like in the link blow

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp

ex : String name = "  my name is Muhamad " ;
we have two spaces before the expression and one after 
so if we applied the .trim() like blow

String newName = name.trim();
we will receive "my name is Muhamad" not "mynameisMuhamad" as a value of newName